# Run-time error '380': Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

I am creating a data entry form on excel.
I followed the link below adapted to my scenario (basically only adding one more column.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P53T6oxgUVA&t=1493s&ab_channel=TheDataLabs

Please see the code below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Reset()
 Dim iRow As Long

iRow = [Counta(ID Database!A:A)] 'Identifying the last row

With frmForm
    .cmbCompany.Clear
    .cmbProgram.Clear
    .cmbProjectPhase.Clear
    .cmbProject.Clear
    .cmbSystem.Clear
    .cmbTest.Clear
    .cmbMedium.Clear
    
    'Adding companies to the combo box
    .cmbCompany.AddItem "XXX"
    .cmbCompany.AddItem "XXX"
    .cmbCompany.AddItem "XXX"
    .cmbCompany.AddItem "XXX"
    
    'Adding Programs to the combo box
    .cmbProgram.AddItem "XXXX"
    
    'Adding Project phases to the combo box
    .cmbProjectPhase.AddItem "X01"
    .cmbProjectPhase.AddItem "X02"
    .cmbProjectPhase.AddItem "X03"
    .cmbProjectPhase.AddItem "X04"
    .cmbProjectPhase.AddItem "X05"
    
    'Adding Projects to the combo box
    .cmbProject.AddItem "Project 1"
    
    'Adding Systems to the combo box
    .cmbSystem.AddItem "System 1"
    .cmbSystem.AddItem "System 2"
    
    'Adding Tests to the combo box
    .cmbTest.AddItem "XXXX Test"       
    .cmbTest.AddItem "XXXX Test"        
    .cmbTest.AddItem "XXXX Test" 
    .cmbTest.AddItem "XXXX Test"     
    .cmbTest.AddItem "XXXX Test"          
    
    'Adding Mediums to the combo box
    .cmbMedium.AddItem "Air"
    .cmbMedium.AddItem "Water"
    
    .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 10
    .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
    .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 70, 60, 70, 70"
    
    
    If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "ID Database!A2:J" & iRow
    Else

        ' the next line for reference
        .lstDatabase.RowSource = "ID Database!A2:J2"

    End If
    
End With
End Sub
```

The code fails specifically at the else statement where the data entered should display on a listbox on the user form once added

```
Sub Generate()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ID Database")

iRow = [Counta(ID Database!A:A)] + 1

With sh
    .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1                                  'Experiment No.
    
    .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.cmbCompany.Value                  'Company
    .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.cmbProgram.Value                  'Program
    .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.cmbProjectPhase.Value             'ProjectPhase
    .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.cmbProject.Value                  'Project
    .Cells(iRow, 6) = frmForm.cmbSystem.Value                   'System
    .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.cmbTest.Value                     'Test
    .Cells(iRow, 8) = frmForm.cmbMedium.Value                   'Medium
    .Cells(iRow, 9) = Application.UserName                      'Submitted by
    .Cells(iRow, 10) = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")]     'Submitted on

End With

End Sub



Sub Show_Form()

frmForm.Show

End Sub
```

Any assistance in eliminating this error is highly appreciated.
I have looked around, and did not manage to find anything that removed the error.

Comment: `.lstDatabase.RowSource = "'ID Database'!A2:J2"`

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. Looking at the code could you give a reason as to why when I enter a record it overwrites the original record instead of going to the next row? I cant see where I went wrong.

Comment: `iRow = [Counta(ID Database!A:A)] + 1` isn't a very reliable to determine the next empty row.   `iRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Williams posted the answer. 
`.lstDatabase.RowSource = "'ID Database'!A2:J2"` 
Thank you very much